# Terminal says command not found on start

Tags: bash

For last few days I'm having this issue. Whenever I open terminal in Ubuntu 16 the first line it says is '$: command not found'.

```
$: command not found
jitendra@jitendra-ubuntu:~ $
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Have a look at your shell startup files to see if there is a stray `$` somewhere. If it's `bash` you're running, look in `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of your shell's initialization files contains a line with a single, lone `$`. Since it is on a line by itself, it is run as a command and since no command with the name `$` exists, you get that error. You need to find and delete that line. Open a terminal and run this command:

```
grep --color -PH '^\s*\$\s*$' ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login \
     ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile \
     /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null
```

That should return a line like:

```
/home/jitendra/.bashrc:$
```

Open the file name that is reported, find the line and delete it.